# How to slice value element in orderedDict in python?

Tags: python, ordereddict

SO,I have this code , how to sliced up value elements in orderedDict?

```
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
x = OrderedDict()
val= np.array((1,2))
key= 40
x[key]= val
x[key]= val,3
print(x)
```

returns :

```
OrderedDict([(40, (array([1, 2]), 3))]) #  <- i want to slice this 2nd value element
```

target output:

```
OrderedDict([(40, array([1, 2])])
```

Comment: What do you mean slice? Do you want to remove the `3`?

Comment: `x[key] = x[key][0]`?

Comment: That's not a slice, it's just extracting the first element. A slice would be another tuple.

Comment: I want to exclude number 3 ,the 2nd value element in displaying orderedDict.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `x[key]` twice?  Do you know that if you took out the second assignment, you'd have what you say you want?  Maybe you do, and you're just setting up to ask your question?  Maybe you just forgot to take the first assignment to `x[key]` out of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Caina is close, but his version is not quite right in that it leaves an extra collection layer in the result.  This is the expression that returns the exact result you requested:

```
x_sliced = OrderedDict({k:x[k][0] for k in x})
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([(40, array([1, 2]))])
```

Actually, this isn't technically what you asked for.  Your version has one missing closing ')', but that's just a typo I assume.

Comment: @ steve ,@ mukul, thanks for your time , code is  working the way i like .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you're using Python 3.6+ or greater:

```
x_sliced = {k:x[k][:1] for k in x}
```

If want to make x_sliced an orderedDict, just type `orderedDict(x_sliced)`.

---

For older versions of Python, or to ensure backward-compatibility:

```
 for key in x:
    x[key] = x_sliced[key]
```

Comment: Two things.  First, I think you have a copy/paste problem in your answer.  You don't mean to have `{k:x[k][:-1] for k in x}` in there twice, do you?  It doesn't compile as is.  Second, if I make that change and run your code, I don't get what the OP asked for.  Rather, I get `OrderedDict([(40, (array([1, 2]),))])`.  Seems there's an extra tuple layered in there.

Comment: adding x[key] = x[key][0] will remove the 2nd value element in orderedDict, i am adding that value for another purpose, i think its kind a hard for me to extract orderedDict without that 2nd value element, but still i will find a way

Comment: @Glenn, I'm not sure what you're saying.  Are you responding to my comment on your original question rather than to this answer?  Is my answer (and as of a few minutes ago, Mukul's answer too) what you wanted?  Other than that, I was just asking what the line `x[key]= val` is there for in your question.  It doesn't do anything, since the next line assigns over what it does by assigning again to `x[key]`, right?  Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Hi @Steve, yeah, I've pasted it twice by mistake, my bad! Thx for noticing, I've edited it now. And indeed, slicing like I did results in a extra tuple layer. Interesting, if I run `len(x_sliced[40])` it returns 1. Again, thx for the comment and your answer =D